# Am I eligible for the stimulus check?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, check, covid-19, stimulus

So my mom claimed me for 2018 Taxes when she shouldn’t have. For 2019 taxes I filed my taxes on April 3rd this year. I am a college student currently part time but my parents do not provide for me financially so they shouldn’t be able to claim me which they didn’t. I support myself with two jobs making over 40k a year My parents didn’t claim me this year. Would I still be eligible for the check?

Comment: I would think you are eligible, but you may need to wait until your 2019 return is processed for the IRS to recognize that.

Comment: It was already processed I received my refund last week for my taxes.

Answer (score 3):

For the stimulus check, the IRS is going to look at your 2019 return first to determine your eligibility. The only reason they would look at 2018 is if you haven't filed for 2019.

You are independent (no one *can* claim you) and your income is below the limit for the phase-out stimulus ($75,000 for single filers). Considering your return for 2019 has already been processed as you stated in the comments, I see no reason why you wouldn't get the stimulus money within the next couple weeks.

Even if your mom did incorrectly claim you for 2019 you will probably still get the money. The IRS will send a letter to both of you to get it sorted out. She lied, you didn't, so there shouldn't be any impact to you.