# Stimulus eligibility check question

Tags: united-states, income-tax, check, covid-19, stimulus

Hopefully one of you may know the answer to this as I can't find it anywhere on the Google and not sure if it's even been asked.

My girlfriend is a healthcare worker who makes less than the threshold for the stimulus payment (so less than 70k). Her parents claimed her as a dependent in 2018 but in 2019 she filed in late March 2020 and she was not claimed as a dependent. Will she eventually get her stimulus payment? I.e in the form of a tax credit for 2020? In 2021.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124004/i-was-claimed-as-a-dependent-in-2018-but-not-in-2019 is somewhat similar. Does that question apply to your situation?

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123993/am-i-eligible-for-the-stimulus-check also has an answer.

Comment: You said she was not claimed as a dependent, but *could* someone have claimed her as a dependent? If someone *could have* claimed her as a dependent, then she would have been required to check the "Someone can claim: You as a dependent" box on her 1040, and she would not get the stimulus payment, even if nobody actually claims her as a dependent.

Comment: Also, whether she gets the check and whether she can claim the tax credit on her 2020 tax return are separate questions. Eligibility for the check is based on her 2019 tax return (or 2018 if she hasn't filed for 2019), whereas eligibility for the tax credit is based on her 2020 tax return. Her tax credit will be reduced by the amount she gets in her check, but not reduced below 0.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the exact same situation where in 2018 i was a dependent, but 2019 i was not. I got my check this morning so i imagine she will receive hers soon as well.

Comment: When you say you "got your check", do you mean you got a direct deposit? Or did you actually get a physical check already?

Comment: Fair question, lol. I got my direct deposit because i filed electronically. Paper checks, i believe, are not expected to be sent out until May

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.